# Rails 4 x SASS: load specific stylesheet in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

In my Rails 4 app, I am trying to implement a conditional to load different stylesheets for Internet Explorer VS. other browsers.

I have an `app/views/layout/_header.html.erb` partial with:

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

And I have the following stylesheets in `app/assets/stylesheets`:

```
custom / # with all my model-specific stylesheets here, such as posts.scss
application.scss
custom.scss
ie.scss
```

In `application.scss` I have:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/theme";
@import "bootstrap-datetimepicker";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "simple_calendar";
@import "custom.scss";
@import "custom/**/*";
```

***Note***: the IE-specific rules in ie.scss are very light, less than 20 lines of code.

However, when I launch the app in Internet Explorer, the CSS rules from `ie.scss` are not taken into account.

How can I make the `ie.scss` file load when the user launches the app in Internet Explorer?

Comment: The IE condition which you have written is **Everything except IE**, change it to, ```<!--[if IE]>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<![endif]-->```. Do not include application stylesheet twice.

Comment: Follow this [blog](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) for conditional stylesheets syntax.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. This fixed the problem. I also had to add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ie.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and now everything is working fine. Feel free to suggest this solution as an answer, I will be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all IE versions:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<!-- Calling application stylesheet file only once -->
<!--[if IE]> 
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> 
<![endif]-->
```

And instead of specifying ie.css, you can change it to:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css )
```

So that you don't have to add each and every file separately.
What I generally use in my projects:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css *.png *.jpg *.jpeg )
```