# Internet Explorer specific styles Rails 5 Sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, sass, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

Internet Explorer as usual is giving me trouble with the padding of an element and it isn't centered vertically (Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Safari are all good).

I created a ie.sass file:

```
.quemsomos-links-desktop-lattes
        padding-top: 10px

.quemsomos-links-desktop-linkedin
        padding-top: 10px
```

On my assets.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ie.css )
```

On my application.html.erb file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<!--[if IE]> 
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> 
<![endif]-->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

According to other answers, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838815/rails-4-x-sass-load-specific-stylesheet-in-internet-explorer) this should be enough for it to display correctly, but IE still doesn't have my specific rules.

Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since no one showed up to help, I decided to dig deeper. Instead of using CSS to target IE, I used JavaScript, following the ideas on this answer:

[How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

```
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
    if(isIE) {
        $('.quemsomos-links-desktop-lattes').css('padding-top', '9px');
        $('.quemsomos-links-desktop-linkedin').css('padding-top', '9px');
    }
```

Seems to be working. I know this is more of a work around than a solution, if anyone can figure it out using just CSS please post below :)